# Virtual Machine in a Virtual Machine - Networking

Tags: networking, vmware, virtualization, freebsd, vps

I have a vps which is virtualised with vmware. I installed vmware workstation and now installing freebsd for testing purposes. Didn't finished the installation but trying to figure out how networking will be held.

I couldn't get additional IP address so will use NAT. How would I be able to use 22 port? I plan to use a prefix to the ports. (like 11 prefix, so 22 port will be 1122) Can it be done by iptables?

Host is CentOS 5, guest will be FreeBSD 7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox solved the problem.